# 19999 geography, medium difficulty

Tags: knowledge, geography

I recently met a time traveller from a distant hypothetical future, and we had an interesting discussion about the geographies of our respective worlds. It turns out that the 19999 world map is pretty similar to what it is now, but there are a few changes. Here are the descriptions of some sovereign states from that future.

Also check out the easy ones in [part one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70545).

> 1. Part of a "federation", my people actually desired independence for a long time. We already voted in favour of it twenty years ago. We are a small island nation, which is not uncommon in this part of the world.
> 2. I'm the third-largest country in North America, slightly larger than Mexico. I was ruled by Europeans for even longer than other countries on our continent.
> 3. Colonialists split our island in half, and it took us a long time to unify our nation. Our population is far from homogenous – in some ways we are as diverse as any country in the world.
> 4. While nominally a "republic", our country has been ruled by foreigners since forever. We fought two wars for our independence, and even after that it took decades to achieve it. It is not easy to be a small country in the shadow of a giant.

Comment: "Twenty years ago" is 1998, not 19979, I guess?

Comment: He travelled from 19999, but we talked this year :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 4 is

> Chechnya (The Chechen Republic) - they fought for independence in two Chechen wars, and they are a small region in the shadow of Russia

and 3 might be

> Timor - currently split in East Timor and West Timor, divided by the Dutch and Portuguese in 1859, and it has quite a diverse population - according to Wikipedia, 11 different ethno-linguistic groups

1 might be

> Nevis - a small island in the Caribbean Sea, part of the Federation of Saint Kitts and Nevis. Independence referendum held in 1998, with the majority voting for independence.

And 2 is maybe

> Quebec - actively seeking independence from Canada, and has a long history of French influence/rule.

**Edit:**

> For #2: My bad. Quebec is not larger than Mexico. I think Greenland (as explained by @1848) fits best.

**Edit 2:**

For 3, maybe a better fit would be

> New Guinea - split to its eastern and western part, formerly a Dutch colony. From Wikipedia: "The island is presently populated by almost a thousand different tribal groups and a near-equivalent number of separate languages, which makes New Guinea the most linguistically diverse area in the world".

Comment: I like all four of these answers! I hope they're right! :D

Comment: #3 fits pretty well, but I think you can find another choice that's even more diverse.

Comment: Aaaand all correct. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @jafe! Looking forward to "19999 geography, difficulty hard" ^^

Answer (score 1):

First

> Puerto Rico

Because

> It fits the clue about voting for independence 20 years ago. Also, Puerto Rico is a small island in the Caribbean, which contains many other small islands.

Second

> Greenland

Because

> Associated with European countries for hundreds of years and is slightly larger than Mexico.

Third

> San Martin

Because

> Split by France and the Netherlands since 1648.

Not quite sure about the fourth yet.

Comment: These are all hypothetical "future" countries that don't exist as sovereign entities now. So #3 is out :)

Comment: #1 would otherwise be an excellent fit, but Puerto Ricans did not in fact vote in favour of independence (only like 3% supported it).

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Puerto Rico

because of [this information](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rican_status_referendum,_1998)

> 2- California

since

> they are somehow trying to get rid of US right now.

Comment: re #3: These are all countries that don't exist as sovereign entities now, so I'm afraid Cyprus doesn't qualify :)

Comment: #1 would otherwise be an excellent fit, but Puerto Ricans did not in fact vote in favour of independence (only like 3% supported it).